# Mythtv MySQL not starting or connecting

Tags: server, mysql, mythbuntu, mythtv

I have re-installed Ubuntu 16.04 and all updates. I added the PPAs for my video card (WinTV-HVR-1265) MythTV 29 and installed both. I cid not get any error messages. I was asked if I was going to use other FE and I said no. So when I try to start the BE for set up it is saying that it cannot connect to the database. That it is waiting to start. I ran a 'service mysql status' and got several blocks of code like this.

```
    ● mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon

> Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2017-11-19 16:43:30 CST; 11min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1346 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           ├─2013 /bin/bash /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
           ├─2170 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --skip-
           └─2171 logger -t mysqld -p daemon error

Nov 19 16:43:28 chuck-OptiPlex-9010 mysqld[2171]: 171119 16:43:28 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
Nov 19 16:43:29 chuck-OptiPlex-9010 mysqld[2171]: 171119 16:43:29 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
Nov 19 16:43:29 chuck-OptiPlex-9010 mysqld[2171]: 171119 16:43:29 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
Nov 19 16:43:29 chuck-OptiPlex-9010 mysqld[2171]: 171119 16:43:29 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.36-8
Nov 19 16:43:29 chuck-OptiPlex-9010 mysqld[2171]: 171119 16:43:29 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
Nov 19 16:43:29 chuck-OptiPlex-9010 mysqld[2171]: 171119 16:43:29 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
Nov 19 16:43:29 chuck-OptiPlex-9010 mysqld[2171]: 171119 16:43:29 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Nov 19 16:43:29 chuck-OptiPlex-9010 mysqld[2171]: Version: '10.0.31-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.16.04.2'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.soc
Nov 19 16:43:30 chuck-OptiPlex-9010 mysql[1346]:    ...done.
Nov 19 16:43:30 chuck-OptiPlex-9010 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon.
```

~
What does anyone think. During setup I was not asked to add any user or passwords. During the loading it is listing Mythtv as the user. I really need some expert guidance, help or a big hammer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get mythTV connected to MySQL you have to import the file `mc.sql`. On Ubuntu it should be located in `/usr/share/mythtv/sql`, so the command would be

```
mysql -uroot -p < /usr/share/mythtv/sql/mc.sql
```

If you haven't set a root password during installation it should be empty, so on the password prompt simply press enter.